# how does the rethrow work when there are multiple programs?

Tags: c++, exception

This program doesn't give the output I expect it to give.

According to my understanding of rethrowing in c++, it should execute the next catch block of the program but it doesn't execute the catch block and instead it's executing the next program. What does rethrow actually do?

The output it gives is "intcaught", but I expected it to output "intcaughtcaught". What's wrong with my reasoning?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class t>
void sign(t a) {
    try {
        throw a;
    } catch (int i) {
        cout << "int";
        throw;
    }
}

main() {
    try {
        sign<int>(1);
        sign<int>('1');
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "caught";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using debugger, it's really good in dealing with this sort of problems

Comment: I tried to clarify your language some, but I'm not sure what you mean by "program" so I was unable to clarify it fully. Could you please explain what you mean by "program"?

Comment: _"instead it's executing the next program"_ What next program?

Comment: `main` needs a return type.

Comment: To answer the title of your question, all exception handling is local to your program.  If your main doesn't catch the exception, then the OS will.  Nothing to do with multiple or other programs.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: OSs do not catch C++ exceptions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: What happens when an exception is thrown and not caught by the program?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The C++ runtime instructs the OS to terminate the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    sign<int>(1);
    sign<int>('1');
} catch (...) {
    cout << "caught";
}
```

The first `sign` call [re-]throws an exception, so execution jumps to printing the `"caught"` text.

That's it.

Execution does not jump back into the `try` block again. So, your second `sign` call never happens.

Your expectation would be satisfied by code of the following form:

```
try {
    sign<int>(1);
} catch (...) {
    cout << "caught";
}

try {
    sign<char>('1');
} catch (...) {
    cout << "caught";
}
```

Notice how I've also changed the template parameter in the second call, otherwise your `"int"` output will show up again.

Answer (score 1):

`sign<int>('1');` is never reached. (If it was, then the `char` literal `'1'` would be converted to an `int` according to the character *encoding* on your platform).

This is because the `throw;` after `cout<<"int";` throws `i` (technically by reference), and that is caught by the catch handler in `main`.